# Does changing hosting or NS servers remove Google warnings?

Tags: google, domains, web-hosting

I have a site which has been rated by Google 'Deceptive' even though it is just a normal, harmless site. I already tried to Report a false warning to Google several times but nothing happened. What if I change NS servers or Hosting Company?? Will it remove the warning?

Comment: If Google already [review your site](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/request_review), and does not remove those warning message then it means that site surely contain some codes to hijack user data.

Comment: What are the precise details of the Google warning?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply move all the same files from one server to another (new hosting company) - keeping the same domain name - then it's unlikely to make any difference. If Google is reporting the site as "Deceptive" then there is something about the site *content* that is dubious.

Are you using any third party advertising networks? Sometimes it might be the adverts that are being served on your site that are malicious. This isn't in the code for your site and might only be served to certain users.

If your site has been hacked then the "deceptive" content might only be served to Googlebot (in order to damage your ranking). It might appear OK to normal users.

> I already tried to Report a false warning to Google

What makes you so sure it is a "false warning"? In my experience, Google is "reasonably quick" to retest a site under such conditions, and removes the "warning" if found to be OK. So if Google continues to report your site as "Deceptive" it would seem to suggest there is still something about your site that it considers "deceptive".